# ZipException while decompressing .zip programmatically

Tags: android, unzip, zipexception

I am trying to decompressing `.zip`, programmatically in my application with the help of this code,

```
public void unzip(String _zipFile, String _targetLocation) {

    dirChecker(_targetLocation);

    try {
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(_zipFile);
        ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
        ZipEntry ze = null;

        while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                dirChecker(ze.getName());
            } else {
                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(_targetLocation + ze.getName());
                for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read()) {
                    fout.write(c);
                }

                zin.closeEntry();
                fout.close();
            }
        }
        zin.close();

        Log.i("xoxo", "unzip: completed!!!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("xoxo", "unzip: err: - " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Everything is fine, but the problem is I am getting an error,

> java.util.zip.ZipException: only DEFLATED entries can have EXT descriptor

While trying to decompress `.zip` created by server that is running on linux environment.

Comment: Maybe your input `zip` file have a `0-byte` entry ?

Comment: `0-byte` entry means ?

Comment: An empty file (or maybe a dir)?

Comment: The problem is that the zip archive contains files that were not compressed (deflated).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library
https://github.com/ankitdubey021/ExtractionLib

```
void extract(){

try {
    File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "value1.jar");
    Extract.extract(outputFile, new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "extration").toString());

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Extracted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}}
```

It will easily extract your zip file. 3 years back I used it in a project. and still working.